# comparar cadenas en javascript

Tags: javascript

Ando algo perdido en javascript, y me gustaria saber como se pueden comparar dos cadenas de texto, es decir, yo escribo una en el la ventane emergente, luego otra y luego por un alert que me compare cual de ellas es mas largas, tengo un ejemplo pero solo me dice de esa cadena cuantos caracteres tiene

```js
var frase=prompt("Igresa cualquier frase");
var frase2=promt("Ingresa la otra frase");
alert(frase.length); //calcula las letras de una frase cualquiera
```

Si alguien me puede decir como hacerlo se lo agradecería un millon de veces.

Comment: Buenas Alex! Bienvenido a [es.so]. Primero, lee el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio. Veo que ya tienes la mitad del trabajo hecho. Tienes la manera de conseguir la longitud de una cadena. ahora solo tienes que compararla con la longitud de otra cadena. Explica mejor tu problema concreto siguiendo [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Operadores_de_comparaci%C3%B3n Aquí podrías ver los operadores lógicos de comparación que existen en Javacript. Con ellos podrías conseguir lo que necesitas.

Comment: El problema es que no estás comparando ambas cadenas. Pregunta la primera frase y almacénala en una variable; después, pregunta la segunda frase y almacénala en otra variable. Cuando las tengas, haz un length a ambas cadenas y una comparación de tipo "mayor que, menor que, igual" (operadores de comparación como te dice PHPMyguel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenido.

Solo te falta comparar las cadenas:

```js
var frase=prompt("Igresa cualquier frase");
var frase2=prompt("Ingresa la otra frase");

if(frase.length > frase2.length){
    alert("Frase es mas larga");
}else{
    alert("Frase2 es mas larga");
}
```

Efectivamente, `.length` da la longitud de una cadena, pero debes comparar después las cadenas, para eso usamos el if, para ver cual es más larga y mostrar el alert según proceda.

Tienes, además, una errata en la variable frase2, no has puesto prompt si no promt, y no muestra el prompt debidamente.

Debes tener en cuenta que si ambas string miden lo mismo te dirá que frase es mas larga, en el segundo script y que frase2 es mas larga en el primero.

Esto es debido a que las letras tienen un peso, en caso de longitud igual no quiere decir que pesen lo mismo, pues una a tiene un peso en bits y una b otro.

Para la cadena de texto asd y bsd la segunda pesará más, pues b tiene un peso mayor que a. Tenlo presente si hay posibilidad de que los usuarios metan frases de la misma longitud.

Comment: Edite, pues no expliqué la verdadera funcionalidad de length y puedes tener problemas en según que usos.

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas calcular cual de los dos largos es mayor, y almacenarlo en una variable para poder mostrarlo después, como se puede ver a continuación:

```js
var text_1 = prompt("Igresa cualquier frase");
var text_2 = prompt("Igresa cualquier frase");

var texto_mas_largo;

if (text_1.length > text_2.length) {
    texto_mas_largo = text_1;
} else {
    texto_mas_largo = text_2;
}

alert("El texto más largo es el siguiente:\n" + texto_mas_largo);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Saul, y a todos los demas por proponer suluciones, estaba probando por mi cuenta un if para frase1 > frase2 y lo mismo pero con else if frase2>1, luego con un else si fuesen igual de largas